# Java - Text Simplifier API

Tags: api, google-api, google-search-api

I am actually developing a text simplifier API in Java which will get the google list of 1000 words and save it in a map. User will enter a word and if it matches the list of words in the map then it will swap it with its synonym.. But I am confused with the synonym part.

How to get the synonym? Do I need to call any external API? Or Google list of words has synonyms along with that?

I have gone through Google it only suggest that the synonym can be founded through WORDAPI but I don't want to use that. What else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that there is a list of words provided by google which are commonly used in english..

Thank you everyone..

It can be founded on below link.

https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/blob/master/google-10000-english.txt#L1